# Angular material as foreignObject inside SVG

Tags: angularjs, svg, angular-material

My general purpose is to make a dynamic and very simple flowchart view. I use svg and angular material. I am trying to show angular material objects like (md-select, md-menu, md-button) inside SVG. After a quick research I saw it is possible with "foreignObject" tags.

Secondly; I want to move all these elements at once inside SVG regarding mouse panning. So I use "viewBox" property.

In my sample;
I use "foreignObject" tag to show angular material "md-select" inside a svg element.

I expect "md-select" to move when I change x and y values of viewBox property of svg element but it keeps its position while clickable area changes.

When I try same scenario with html "select" it moves as I expect. But I can't do the same with angular material objects. (they visually stay in their original position but their click area goes another where regarding viexBox x-y values.)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

   x: <input ng-model="vbx">
   y: <input ng-model="vby">

<svg id="processDesignPanel" viewBox="{{vbx}} {{vby}} 500 500" name="processDesignPanel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="800px" height="800px">

  <foreignObject width="100" height="50" x="100" y="100">
    <md-select placeholder="Assign to user" ng-model="userkey" style="width: 200px;">
      <md-option ng-repeat="user in formusers">{{user}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
  </foreignObject> 

  <foreignObject width="100" height="50" x="100" y="200">
    <select placeholder="Assign to user" ng-model="userkey" style="width: 150px;">
      <option ng-repeat="user in formusers">{{user}}</option>
    </select>
  </foreignObject>

</svg>

</div>
```

sample js

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.formusers=["ally","mike"];


    $scope.vbx=null;
    $scope.vby=null; 
})
```

[here is my fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ErSe/990ekrqz/)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete solution, but I think it's a couple steps in that direction. I cut down your fiddle to show the incorrectly-placed MD select along with the correctly-placed regular select, with a button that modifies the style of the md-select-value tag to have position:inherit and z-index:auto, which makes the MD select appear in the correct place. I don't know why it does this, yet, as I haven't delved into the lib's CSS.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('md-select-value')[0].setAttribute('style','z-index:auto; position:inherit')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emamid/n8tr0gfk/6/